# FTP filemove in shell script

Tags: shell, ftp

I need to move a file from one server to another FTP server using Shell Script.

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST='ftp.server.com'
USER='username'
PASSWD='password'
FILE='"/a/b/test.sh"'
DIR='/x/y/'

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
cd $DIR
put $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

Here my question is,

I need to select a file from the server and put it into the FTP's particular location. My original file is in `/a/b/test.sh` path. That should be moved to `/x/y` path of FTP.

What am I missing.. I am new to shell script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `lcd` command which changes the working directory on the local machine.

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST='ftp.server.com'
USER='username'
PASSWD='password'
LOCALPATH='/a/b/'
FILE='test.sh'
DIR='/x/y/'

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
cd $DIR
lcd $LOCALPATH
put $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

Comment: if I have 2 files like '/a/b/test.sh' and '/a/b/test1.sh', then what all are the changes I should make to move both files to FTP..?

Comment: One option is to use `FILE1='test.sh'` and `FILE2='test2.sh'. Then `put $FILE1` and `put $FILE2`. Second option is to use the `mput` command if supported by the FTP server.

Comment: Thanks.. If the file names are generated dynamically, then can we loop the /a/b/ dir and move to ftp..? If so, what should be changed.?ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
cd $DIR
lcd $LOCALPATH
for entry in "&LOCALPATH"*
do
put $ENTRY
done
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0. I tried like this

Comment: You may use `mput` FTP command. Please look at the reference/help of `mput` FTP command.